# Ruby on Rails - Override application.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm trying to override my application.css with other css, included in header. I want to customize my application.css by this way.

**My header**

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
= stylesheet_link_tag 'customized_css', media: 'all'
```

**Actual**

[image]

application.css.scss is overriding my tour.css.scss even its is loading before any other css

### Edit

The order of files to override the style was right but application's selector specificity beats the tour's, so that's why. Solution - use ID instead.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

[Specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Thanks to [@tonyedwardspz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3194491/tonyedwardspz) for the solution

Comment: So what’s stopped you then?

Comment: application.css has still higher priority, no matter on the order

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Edit: added image. I want my tour.css.scss to override application.css.scss

Comment: Is your issue with with the specificity of the selector in tour.css?

Comment: Do you think its caused by selector? @tonyedwardspz

Comment: Possibly. You've declared the stylesheets in the right order, tour.css should override. You could use an id to target that element to test the thory, It will override all other selectors.

Comment: Oh, thanks! @tonyedwardspz I calculated the specificity of my selectors and application's selector beats the tour selector

Comment: I generally give my body tag a specific id and class, based on the controller and action, so I can write very specific css for a page if needed. Imho easier. And everything can be compiled into one application.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is with CSS specificity.

You have declared the css files in the right order. However, the rule within `tour.css.scss` has a lower level of css specificity and therefore cannot override the declaration in `application.css.scss`.

To solve you can do one of three things:

- Rewrite the rule to have a higher speceficity. Applying a class to the element and combining that with the existing rule in `tour.css.scss`
- Rewrite the rule to match the selectors declared in `application.css.scss`. This will allow the cascade to work as you expect, but may affect other on page elements.
- Apply a class to the body tag that is specific to each page. You can then target your selections to only one page.

You can read more about css specificity [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).